# What are "multi point triggers"?

Tags: database, couchdb

Is anyone familiar with this term?  Can't find much about it on the interwebs.

It's quoted in the CouchOne announcement. http://www.couchone.com/merger-technical-vision

Also referred to here http://public.dhe.ibm.com/partnerworld/pub/pdf/courses/z1a06.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was curious about this too after reading the question so I asked their tech support.  This is what they said:

> If you are familiar with CouchDB's _changes feed, and _update, _show
>   and _list functions, that is the basic idea, to apply that programming
>   model to more of the database internals.

Answer (score 0):

I think what it means is that the trigger can be fired on several "events", e.g. on update , on insert, on delete etc..

My 2 cents